# MongoDB: Check to see if object is in array before before updating entry

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb

Forgive me as I'm pretty new to Mongoose and MEAN in general.

I am curious if an if statement like this would work to prevent a user from pushing themselves into an array twice.

Right now I'm using ng-hide to hide the 'attend' button, but I'd like to learn of a way to prevent it altogether in mongoose.

```
export function attending(req: express.Request, res: express.Response, next: Function){

    if(req.params.id.attending.indexOf(req['payload']._id) !== -1) {

    Event.update({_id: req.params.id}, {$push: {'attending': req['payload']._id }, $inc: {numGuests: -1}}, (err)=> {
        if (err) return next (err)
        User.update({user}, {$push: {'attending': event}}, (err)=> {
            if(err) return next (err);
            res.json({message: "You're In!"});
        })
    });
  }
}
```

Here is the model

```
let eventSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: {type: String, required: true},
  name:{type: String, required: true},
  eventAddress: { type: String, required: true},
  dateCreated: {type: Number},
  eventCreator: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true },

  attending: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}]
});
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Don't know what you have in your paramters, but the "queries" themeselves should be represented as "objects" and not "values" wrapped in brackets `{}`. If you want to see if someone is not already in an array then test it with `$ne`. i.e `Event.update({ "_id": id, "attending": { "$ne": user } }, { "$push": { "attending": user }, "$inc": { "numGuests": -1 } }, (err,numAffected) => { .. })` That way there is no "match" to update if the user is already there. Answered many times here already.

Comment: Yeah, I added that last second...don't know why.

so I'm going to google $ne! Thank you!

Comment: Documentation [`$ne`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/). You should also spend some time familarizing yourself with all the [operators](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/) in general.

Comment: Awesome awesome awesome! that's what I needed to see!